# Does Linkedin provide JavaScript API for Company Search?

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I'm writing a widget solely in JavaScript and trying to avoid any server-side scripting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no pre-built [Company Search](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-search) methods for the [JavaScript API](https://developer.linkedin.com/javascript). You'd need to make the company search request via the `IN.API.Raw()` method, something like:

```
IN.API.Raw('/company-search?keywords=LinkedIn')
  .result(function(value) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(value));
  })
  .error(function(error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

Here is the documentation for Company Search;
[Doc](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields)

[Link to API](http://developer.linkedin.com/)

Comment: You do realize I'm asking about JavaScript API? Such as for search profile we use IN.API.Profile(id) ....